# Laravel 5.2 upgrade causes sql lock error, doesn't respect database transactions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

We were getting along just fine with some Eloquent code in Laravel 5.1:

```
DB::transaction(function () {

  // Eloquent model saved here
  $bla = new Bla();
  $bla->blabla = 'bla';
  $bla->save() 

});
```

The Bla Eloquent model has a model observer class which checks for creates, updates, and deletes, and subsequently writes to a log table. In Laravel 5.1 this worked flawlessly but after upgrading to 5.2 it seems to forget it's in a transaction and throws this error because it actually attempts to write to the log table:

```
General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Mind you this also fails in 5.2 when we tried using model events. The event/observer tries to write immediately to the log table instead of when the transaction is committed. Is there a way to get observer/event classes to work properly inside a transaction in Laravel 5.2 or should I revert to Laravel 5.1? My current theory is that since the observer is one level removed from the transaction, something in the new code introduced a bug that no longer respects the transaction at this level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if you are using multiple DB connections pointing to the same database and the observer/listener is on a different connection to the default one.

This happened to me and the fix was to make sure the observer was on the default (or same) connection.

Comment: Thanks Big Al. That was indeed the problem.